# Error Reading Migration File (Java Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, boot, liquibase

При запуске проекта появляется ошибка:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error Reading Migration File: class path resource [db/changelog/changelog.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

Пути указаны верно, как я думаю. Просмотрел много подобных вопросов на разных форумах, ничего не помогло.

Вот папка ресурсов:

[image: проект]

в properties  указаны следующие значения:

```
spring.liquibase.enabled=true
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/changelog.xml
```

В changelog.xml:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

<include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="v1.0/changelog-v1.0.xml"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

В changelog-v1.0.xml:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

<include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="bi_schema.xml"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: `db.changelog` это у Вас одна папка в ОС?

Comment: нет, есть еще проекты в которых есть такой путь @Tsyklop

Comment: Вопрос не в этом. Вопрос в том, это папка с именем с точкой, или это вложенные папки (`changelog` в `db`), а IDE их схлопывает и показывает с точкой.

Comment: @RomanKonoval У меня папка db, внутри которой changelog

Comment: Добавьте `/` в начале пути: `spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/changelog.xml`

Comment: @RomanKonoval Это не помогло. Да и смысла в этом нет, так как слэш вначале убирается в ClassPathResource

Comment: Значит какая-то проблема с конфигурацией проекта. При запуске через maven/gradle та же проблема? Если нет - то проблема в том, как проект запускается в IDE (эти ресурсы не в classpath). Если есть, то проблема в конфигурации именно mvn/gradle.

Comment: @RomanKonoval При запуске с maven, проблема та же

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Пути все верны, но оказалось, что есть одна ошибка в pom.xml

Заключается она в том, что там написана строчка, которую надо удалить.

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Так как в проекте всего один модуль.